# xcode replaces tabs by spaces after a branch merge

Tags: ios, xcode, git, merge, whitespace

After a merge of two branches, and resolving conflicts, Xcode modifies two files: the .plist and the .pbxproj of the project. In both cases, the **leading tabs of every line are replaced by spaces**.

Also after finishing the merge and creating the corresponding commit, Xcode leaves all the files that had conflicts without adding them to the commit, forcing us to make a second commit with the resolved files (including .plist and .pbxproj). Only happens with those two files and only if they have conflicts on the merge, other file types (.h, .m) not affected.

**Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b)**

- The number of spaces added, corresponds to the number of tabs present: 4 spaces per tab.
- In the Xcode Preferences, all the team have selected "Spaces" in "Prefer indent using: under Indentation.

We would like to know how to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Having a similar issue but it appears to only be the pbxproj file and only certain lines, in particular the lines dealing with Provisioning Profile and Signing.

Comment: What I noticed is: every time you do a merge and are presented with the merge editor, whatever file you open in that editor will have the tabs replaced with spaces. It doesn't matter if there is a conflict or not, if you view the file, it's going to be changed when you press `Merge`. I usually look at the merge changes, see if they look alright, cancel the merge and then merge again without viewing any of the files in the editor in order to avoid that tabs -> spaces change, but that only works for no-conflict merges.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because of indentation settings in one of the systems your team use:

[image]

If you have swift lint in your project, that's can cause it too.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried to solve the problem, but it didn't work. All the members of the team have the preferred indent set to spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Often you have your xcode settings overriden by project settings, so don't forget to check them here as well:
[image: project "Text Settings" which defines indent using spaces and its widths]